# gitlab ERROR: Unknown Author while trying to push changes

Tags: git, gitlab, author

I have this problem from yesterday but can't solve myself.
Example my user name is:  My Name
           user id is:    my.name
This shows following error:

```
remote: ********************************************************************************        
remote: ERROR: Unknown Author.         
remote: found My Name (name.my)        
remote: Please contact your GIT administrator and/or consult Confluence
```

I don't understand why my gitlab id was reverted (my.name --> name.my) while trying to connect to repo. Should I have any changes in config file to solve this problem?

it is a problem of git configuration or about the repository?

Comment: To ssh://cj03.ccpdev.net:11022/srsng-test/srsng.git
! refs/heads/Dung:refs/heads/Dung [remote rejected] (hook declined)

Answer (score 0):

Git will use your configured username and email.  To check what `git` thinks your name and email are, use:

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

These values need to reflect your remote user (the one in the target git instance). 
 If you need to change either then use:

```
git config --global user.name "My Name"
git config --global user.email "my.name@example.com"
```